# chef exec rspec cannot find the path specified

Tags: rspec, chef-infra

When I try to run `chef exec rspec` I keep getting

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

C:\opscode\chefdk\bin is there in my system path. I am using windows 7 as my work station. I am not sure which path it is trying to look for?
I have installed the chefdk on my `D:` drive instead of `C:`. My best guess is that there is some place where `C:\` is hardcoded.

Comment: does a `chef -h` works ?

Comment: yes it works fine.

Comment: Well, if your chefdk is in d:\opscode\chefdk and your path is c:\opscode\chefdk, there's indeed a problem. Most of omnibus packaging of chef is hardcoded to the default install location to avoid conflicts with system ruby and other things, that's probably your problem.

Comment: Yes so the issue was with the ` D:\` I resinstalled chefdk on `C:` and things worked.

Answer (score 0):

Most of omnibus packaging of chef is hardcoded to the default install location to avoid conflicts with system ruby and other things.

Re-installing chefdk on `C:\` drive fixed this issue.

Comment: it's also notable that chef exec really just handles ruby and environment variables, so assuming that `rspec` is in `C:\opscode\chefdk\bin` you can just flat out type it alone and omit the `chef exec` portion